If $G(M)$ is a finitely-generated $G(A)$-module, then $M$ is a finitely-generated $A$-module.
This question comes from proposition 10.24 in Commutative Algebra by Atiyah Macdonald.
Proposition 10.24: Let $A$ be a ring, $a$ an ideal of $A$, $M$ an $A$-module, $(M_n)$ an $a$-filtration of $M$. Suppose that $A=\hat{A}$ and that M is Hausdorff in its filtration topology. Suppose also that $G(M)$ is a finitely-generated $G(A)$-module, then $M$ is a finitely-generated $A$-module.
The proof in the book: Pick a finite set of generators of $G(M)$, and split them up into their homogeneous components, say $\xi_i$$(1\leq i\leq r)$ where $\xi_i$ has degree say $n(i)$, and is therefore the image of say $x_i\in M_{n(i)}$. Let $F^i$ be the module $A$ with the stable $a$-filtration given by $F_k^i=a^{k+n(i)}$ and put $F=\oplus_{i=1}^rF^i$. Then mapping the generator $1$ of each $F^i$ to $x_i$ defines a homomorphism $$\phi : F\to M$$of filtered groups, and $G(\phi):G(F)\to G(M)$ is a homomorphism of $G(A)$-modules......
My questions:

Why $F^i=A$ with the stable $a$-filtration given by $F_k^i=a^{k+n(i)}$ ?

The $a$-filtration of $F$ is $(\oplus_{i=1}^r F_n^i)$. How can I define $\phi$ ? What is the form of $\phi$ ? Why $\phi$ is a homomorphism of filtered groups ?


Associated graded ring $G(M)=\oplus_{n=0}^\infty M_n/M_{n+1}$, $(M_n)$ is an $a$-filtration of $M$.

Please add the definition of $G(M)$.

$G(M)=\oplus_{n=0}^\infty{M_n}/{M_{n+1}}$, $(M_n)$ is an a-filtration of $M$.

I think the filtration on $F^i$ is not a filtration in the sense of Atiyah-Macdonald, since $F^i_0 = a^{n(i)} \neq A$. Maybe you need to shift all the existing filtrations up (padding by copies of the module) by $N = \max(n(1),\ldots,n(r))$ and then set $F^i_k = \mathfrak{a}^{k + \max(0, N - n(i))}$? Or like, work with filtrations that can start at a negative number
